# Is it possible to replace a color in a base 64-encoded image?

Tags: javascript, css, base64

Is there any way to take a base 64 string, for example:

```
.copyIcon {background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAW0lEQVR42mNgQALCi7//J4QZcAFiNOM1hJANBA0h1QC83iHFizDJ/dgww/7/LAQNwKUZbkjDfya8YQZXiCqJagilBmAzhLYGYDNsJBhAMD3gS854NS/6vg+fZgDKvmW19S7PRAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") center center no-repeat;}
```

And replace a solid color with another solid color using JavaScript?

In this specific example I have a solid color in the icon (`#13A3F7`) that I would like to replace with another solid color (`#ff6400`).

The reason for doing this is it is not a one-off. I would like to be able to change the icon to *any* color with a setting.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a little function which takes 3 parameters: data, colorFrom, colorTo (both colors should be supplied in hex)

```
function changeColInUri(data,colfrom,colto) {
    // create fake image to calculate height / width
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = data;
    img.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = img.offsetHeight;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

    // remove image
    img.parentNode.removeChild(img);

    // do actual color replacement
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var data = imageData.data;

    var rgbfrom = hexToRGB(colfrom);
    var rgbto = hexToRGB(colto);

    var r,g,b;
    for(var x = 0, len = data.length; x < len; x+=4) {
        r = data[x];
        g = data[x+1];
        b = data[x+2];

        if((r == rgbfrom.r) &&
           (g == rgbfrom.g) &&
           (b == rgbfrom.b)) {

            data[x] = rgbto.r;
            data[x+1] = rgbto.g;
            data[x+2] = rgbto.b;

        } 
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

An additional function is required to convert hex colors to RGB (for correct matching)

```
function hexToRGB(hexStr) {
    var col = {};
    col.r = parseInt(hexStr.substr(1,2),16);
    col.g = parseInt(hexStr.substr(3,2),16);
    col.b = parseInt(hexStr.substr(5,2),16);
    return col;
}
```

Usage would be like so:

```
changeColInUri(
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAW0lEQVR42mNgQALCi7//J4QZcAFiNOM1hJANBA0h1QC83iHFizDJ/dgww/7/LAQNwKUZbkjDfya8YQZXiCqJagilBmAzhLYGYDNsJBhAMD3gS854NS/6vg+fZgDKvmW19S7PRAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
    "#13A3F7",
    "#ff6400"
);
```

It will return a new data:image/png; URI with the swapped colors, here is a working jsfiddle of the end result

http://jsfiddle.net/V5dU2/

(tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE10)

Comment: Great thinking. Note that it does require `<canvas>` support, which IE 8 and earlier don’t have natively.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite IMHO, as IE 8 doesn't even play well with data URI (32KB for max length), this should not be a problem.

Comment: From what I have read on caniuse.com the IE problem (as you note, depending on size) is with data URIs in HTML, not in CSS...if that helps.

Comment: Hi there, great answer and script. Implemented it. However, on the first load it seems to always output a transparent png. When using the script on user interaction it seems to work fine. Anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: `DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0`