# Change color from an base64 Vector image with jQuery

Tags: css, image, vector, svg, effect

how can i change the color from an base64 vector image like that

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2l...............Pg0KPC9zdmc+DQo=">
```

the normal way with css doesnt work

```
img:hover { fill:#006600; }
```

**demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/9Vn7v/

If found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419101/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-color-in-a-base-64-encoded-image) .... but this function needs the current color (that i dont know) from the image.

Comment: You'd have to extract the data from the src attribute, convert it from base64, load it using DOMParser, edit it and then recode it to base64 and stick it back in the image src attribute. Easier to just encode the image with the right colour.

Comment: i this a big process for the browser (CPU load)? I want to change the color from many images at the same time ... If not, this is a solution for me. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Probably. You'd be better off doing things a completely different way e.g. embed the SVG directly or use an `<object>` tag.